# Switch case execute code without breaking C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is it possible in C# to execute a switch case without breaking?

This is an example of a switch where using break in desired

```
var bar = "Foo";
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        bar += " Bar";
    case 2:
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

This is what the code should produce:

```
0: Foo Bar
1: Foo Bar
2: Bar
3: Bar
Else: nothing
```

Is it possible to do this or would I have to do:

```
var bar = "Foo";
if(foo == 0 || foo == 1) bar += " Bar";
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called implicit fall through which is not supported in C#.

You can use `goto case` statement though.

```
var bar = "Foo";
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        bar += " Bar";
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code, if `switch` case is not mandatory in your code.
You can try something like this:

```
var bar = "Foo";
if(foo == 0 || foo == 1) bar += " Bar";
if(foo >= 0 && foo <= 3) //Replacement of switch with single if condition
    Console.WriteLine(bar);

Output:
if foo == 1 then print -> "Foo Bar"
if foo == 3 then print -> "Foo"
```